# table stores has two columns like store_id and products. Write a SQL query to find store_ids which sell only shampoo and biscuit

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

Store should sell only two products and that too only shampoo and biscuit

For example
[image]

Output:
[image]

my query: -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT store_id AS gp_str
      FROM (SELECT store_id,
                   COUNT(product) AS prd_cnt
            FROM stores
            GROUP BY store_id) x
      WHERE x.prd_cnt = 2) y
     LEFT JOIN stores ON y.gp_str = stores.store_id;
```

My query gave me result of stores which sell only two products but I wanted stores which sell two products which are shampoo and biscuit only.

Comment: When asking a SQL question please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot make use of an image of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is Relational Division. Do you want stores that sell *exactly* those two items, no more no less? Please supply sample data *as text*

Comment: That would be quite an interesting approach to product range to **only** sell those two things!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find exact match of a set of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530305/how-to-find-exact-match-of-a-set-of-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT store_id
FROM stores
GROUP BY store_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product) = 2
    AND COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN product IN ('shampoo','biscuit') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```